# Given $T\in \mathcal{L}(V)$ which has $n$ eigenvalues in $K$. Show that if there is a $k\in \mathbb{N}$ with $T^{k+1}=T$ then T is diagonalizable.

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations, diagonalization

I am thinking about the following problem:

> Let $V$ be an $n$-dimensional vector space over $K$ and let $T:V\rightarrow V$ be an endomorphism which has $n$ eigenvalues in $K$. Show that if there is a natural number $k\in \mathbb{N}$ with $T^{k+1}=T$ then $T$ is diagonalizable.

In this type of statement I don't know if I should consider the $n$ eigenvalues pairwise distinct or not necessarily. I understand that if it says that there are $n$ eigenvalues, then they are only considering the pairwise different eigenvalues in the counting. So, under this reasoning, if I consider the eigenvalues are pairwise distinct then the $n$ eigenvectors associated to each of those eigenvalues are linearly independent and then V has a basis of eigenvectors, therefore $T$ is diagonalizable. (Without using the fact that $T^{k+1}=T$ for some $k\in \mathbb{N}$.)

Please tell me if my reasoning is correct or not. Is it correct to consider the eigenvalues are pairwise different in this type of statement? Any suggestion or solution are welcome.

The problem is from Karlheinz Spindler's *Abstract algebra with applications* vol. 1, page 227

Comment: Presumably, the eigenvalues are counted with multiplicity. If they were pairwise distinct, then the characteristic polynomial would be a product of distinct linear factors, and thus diagonalizable.

Comment: If you're trying to prove that the eigenvalues of $T$ all have multiplicity $1$, then you're not going to get far. If $K = \Bbb{C}$, then $\lambda I$ where $\lambda$ is a $k$th root of unity (or $0$) is an example of such a $T$, but their eigenvalues have multiplicity greater than $1$ (for $n > 1$).

Comment: @Reveillark What do you mean with "counted with multiplicity"?

Comment: @Joshua, essentially, it means that repetition is allowed.

Comment: For instance, the polynomial $(x - 1)^3$ has three roots, but they are all $1.$

Comment: @Carlo so, following your example I should say that an endomorphism with that characteristic polynomial has 3 eigenvalues?Or it says that it has only 1 eigenvalue (but with algebraic multiplicity distinct of 1)? I think that is my main doubt.

Comment: @Joshua, if the $n$ eigenvalues are distinct, then the problem is trivial: the minimal polynomial is the characteristic polynomial, and the characteristic polynomial splits into distinct linear factors.

Answer (score 3):

No, you don't know the eigenvalues are distinct, just there are $n$ eigenvalues in $K$ (counted with algebraic multiplicity).  I think you also need to assume $\operatorname{char}K=0$.  Use $T^{k+1}=T$ to get the min poly is a product of distinct linears, hence diagonalizable.